# Существует ли слово "разрешивается"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Услышала по радио, как диктор говорит "проблема разрешивается". Существует ли такое слово?

Answer (score 3):

Форма слова *разрешиваться* [некорректна](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-paradigm-term-61007.htm).